# Get the final generated html source using c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

using VB.net or c#, How do I get the generated HTML source?

To get the html source of a page I can use this below but this wont get the generated source, it won't contain any of the html that was added dynamically by the javascript in the browser. How do I get the the final generated HTML source?

thanks

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.asp.net"); 
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse(); 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()); 
string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

if I try this below then it returns the document with out the JavaScript code injected

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim WB As WebBrowser = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        WB = New WebBrowser()
        Me.Controls.Add(WB)
        AddHandler WB.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted


        WB.Navigate("mysite/Default.aspx")

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)


        'Dim htmlcode As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml()
        Dim s As String = WB.DocumentText

    End Sub
End Class
```

HTML returned

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="center_text_panel">
    //test text  this text should be here
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("center_text_panel").innerText = "test text";


    </script>
```

Comment: Use WEbbrowser control.

Comment: Do you have an example? have you done it before as I tried that but could not get it to work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Hello-World?  I'm having the SAME issue and tried using the new WebView2 control from MS, but still no love!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/)

[Look here](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php) for official tutorials

This can not only grab the source, but also process javascript through the pageload event.

```
webKitBrowser1.Navigate(MyURL)
```

Then, handle the DocumentCompleted event, and:

```
private documentContent = webKitBrowser1.DocumentText
```

**Edit** - This might be the better open source WebKit option: http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/

Comment: +1, also I think "need" is too strong here - built in WebBrowser or even PhantomJS can be used to do the same.

Comment: The webkit is giving me the source HTML and not the final generated.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `webbrowser` control to your form and you flowing code:

```
 webBrowser1.Navigate("YourLink");

     private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           string htmlcode= webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml;//Or Each Filed Or element..//WebBrowser.DocumentText
        }
```

**Edited**

for getting also html code that generated dynamically by java script code you have two way:

1. run flowing code after `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` Event

> ```
>  StringBuilder htmlcode = new StringBuilder();
>             foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.All)
>             {
>                 htmlcode.Append( item.InnerHtml);
>             }
> ```

1. write a javascript code for returning `document.documentElement.innerHTML` and using InvolkeScript Function To Return Result:

> ```
>    var htmlcode = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("javascriptcode");
> ```

Comment: thanks that s great  but it returns the source not the generated souce

Comment: For Getting dynamically Generated Code You must Using extra JavaScript Code if You if add more details of something that you want to do it will show solution(or adding some extra code)

Comment: Hi  - WebBrowser.DocumentText needs to return the generated html code with the javascript injected into it. Do you think that this might need to be done as async. thanks for your help.

Comment: The string returned is just HTML before javascript runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml
```