# Where is the file located that holds the generated HTML page source code in safari?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, browser-history

Where is the file located that holds the generated HTML source code in safari?

The `.webhistory` files aren't useful for what I need, while the browser is displaying the website, where is it temporarily saving the generated source code?

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

---

In any other browser would be fine as well.

Clarify: I know how to view the generated source code, but I want to know where safari is temporarily holding it. I need it to use as automated input file every time I visit a page rather than view option, copy, and paste. As that wouldn't allow automation for the rest of my program.

Comment: are you talking about the HTML?  right clicking and choosing the View Source option will show the generated HTML "source".  The true source code is most likely not available to you.

Comment: I know of the view source option to see the html generated code, but I want to know where safari has the containing file of it. That way I can use it as input in a program automatically every time i visit a page without having to go to the option and copy paste.

Comment: your program should make a webrequest and receive it directly.  doing it file based doesn't sound like a realistic option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using webrequest. I'm a new ruby programmer limited to ruby, html, and css. I can't figure out nor find a source that shows how to get the generated HTML source code instead of the normal HTML source code. I found this, but not knowing javascript, c#, or vb.net I can't use it. Seems that it should be very possible in ruby as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847656/get-the-final-generated-html-source-using-c-sharp-or-vb-net Also can't comment there, because it requires 50 reputation to comment. Spent a long time searching, any advice would be appreciated. Thanks