# C# WebBrowser control - document does not contain html input control

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How to access (read and fill) html controls that are visible on my webbrowser control (DocumentComplete reached) and on chrome in fire-bug but not in html source ?
I was trying this solutions but they dont work for me ("read html after ajax upload", "sleep thread", etc)

- [C# WebBrowser control -- Get Document Elements After AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635948/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-get-document-elements-after-ajax)
- [Get the final generated html source using c# or vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847656/get-the-final-generated-html-source-using-c-sharp-or-vb-net)
- [How to get rendered html (processed by Javascript) in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)
  etc

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I posted a bunch of samples doing that, go through the list of links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).

Comment: Thanks, looks useful.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/991058 your solution is working. Thank you !