# How to open a web form in current tab instead of new tab?

Tags: c#, .net

How to open a web form to replace current tab instead of new tab?
I am using the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://localhost:51571/Login.aspx");
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

Comment: You can't do this with `Process` class as far as i think, you should go for `WebBrowser` control for this purpose which really deals with webpages.

Comment: A webbrowser is a control so the control has to be added to the tab.  I'm not sure what you are exactly doing.  I have my own project where I added multiple panels to a form and then added a webbrowser to each panel (in your case a tab control).   You can use Navigate to your login page.  See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847656/get-the-final-generated-html-source-using-c-sharp-or-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

You want to Navigate from One Web form to another? If that was the case You can use

> Response.Redirect("Default.aspx") other wise provide more details about the question.

Comment: It shows error : Response is not available in this context when i use response.redirect

Comment: Which Editor you are using. Is it Visual Studio or some other?

Comment: If it is web application, then Request and Response objects will come in the intellisense. Try to  put the code in any event like page load or button click..etc.